# How do I get the "old style" system print dialog for Chrome on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, printing

In our office, a colleague obviously has a problem with their Chrome installation (15.0.847.106m). The print dialog does not show any preview, and it doesn't show the printers as well.

[image]

Other browsers like Firefox *do* show the printers.

In OS X, I know that the "old style" system print dialog can be triggered with `⌥⌘P`. Is there an equivalent for Windows? Where else should I look?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the system shortcut (in Windows or GNU/Linux) `Ctrl-Shift-P` to see the system dialog for printing as you desired, or you can *disable* Chrome's print preview alltogether if you type `about:flags` in the URL bar, scroll a little bit down, and disable Print Preview and then restart Google Chrome.

[image: about:flags]

Comment: Disabling print preview altogether fixed it for him, thanks!

Comment: It's been five years and Google has removed the setting named "Print Preview". Is there a new way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

These days you can disable the print preview and always get the system dialog by setting the policy [DisablePrintPreview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies?policy=DisablePrintPreview) to true.

I've only had a chance to try this with Chromium on Linux, but on Windows it looks like you should be able to create the registry key `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\DisablePrintPreview` as a `DWORD` set to 1. [In an enterprise environment you may also be able to set via the Group Policy editor as well](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en). Either way, you can navigate to `chrome://policy/` in Chrome to see whether Chrome is picking up the policies.